# How to add class or ID to div containing errors in PHP

Tags: html, php

When PHP encounters an error, it displays the Error or Warning message in a `div` with some inline style. I wish to add a `class="some-class"` or `id="some-id"` attribute to the `div` so that I can do a little styling in my CSS file. Is that possible and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Never use an ID twice in the same page. PHP errors are printed en masse, so use a class instead**. Find the following two lines in your `php.ini` file (on my Ubuntu box, it's in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`:

```
error_prepend_string
error_append_string
```

And change them to suit your needs. I use inline styles with them so I don't have to add anything into my stylesheet, but you could of course add a class. This is my setup:

```
error_prepend_string = "<div style='font-weight: bold; color: red'>Error: "
error_append_string = "</div>"
```

Yours might be something like this:

```
error_prepend_string = "<div class='phpError'>Error: "
error_append_string = "</div>"
```

Comment: That doesn't work about it? I take it you've seen an error printed, and it's not wrapped in anything? Use an inspector like Firebug (FF) or Chrome's developer tools to see if the error is wrapped in a `div`.

Comment: What OS are you using? And you're using Apache 2 I take it?

Comment: I am using windows 7 and apache2 of course. I checked the values in phpinfo and the values are shown correctly. But somehow the values are appended to the error messages. I don't think it should be so complex. Sorry for taking your lot of time.

Comment: Not a problem. Glad you got it working. Just out of interest, what was the problem you were having?

Comment: I have a little complex front-end design of my application with Divs overlapping. Sometimes an error would not be visible directly because it would be shown under some Div. So i wrote a little CSS and z-index for the PhpError Div which makes it always visible on top of other layers. Do you think there would have been a better way out?

Comment: No I think that's fine, although it's always a good practice to make front-end design as simple as possible :-)